# $_FILES reports error 1 (file size) despite upload_max_size and post_max_size set properly

Tags: php, apache

I'm uploading a 2MB file to my server and when I `print_r($_FILES)` it's reporting an error code #1, which evidently indicates a file size problem.  I've already set the following in my php.ini:

```
post_max_size=100M
upload_max_filesize=100M
```

I've also verified that these changes have taken effect by displaying `phpinfo()`, but I'm still getting the same error.  This is in an application that was moved from a shared development webhost to a dedicated VPS.  It worked fine on the shared host but I'm getting the error on the VPS.

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Comment: can you post the exact error message that you are getting ?

Comment: You could try outputting the max file size at runtime insteaf of in the sanitized phpinfo().. perhaps there is code resetting it after php.ini

Comment: Is Suhosin installed (check your phpinfo())?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Sure, the error is Array([file_name] => Array([error] => 1)).  There is no PHP error unless I print the $_FILES array.

Comment: @Wade Williams I just did a print ini_get(upload_max_filesize) and it's reporting 100M.

Comment: @Paulpro No, doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Does it allow any uploads at all? file_uploads = Off/On

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a support ticket to my webhost.  Somehow the server was not responding to my php.ini file despite the proper values displaying in phpinfo().  The solution was to add the following to my .htaccess file:

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myaccount/public_html 
<Files php.ini> 
order allow,deny 
deny from all 
</Files>
```

I'm not sure why this was necessary when phpinfo() reported the changes but this did the trick.